# How can you compare two observables to find a value is not in both?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two `observables` one is a list of available courses and one is a list of coursework completed.  My task is it create a list of courses that can be taken next.  The problem is when I do a filter I can find where the compare is true easy enough but I can't figure out how to get the inverse list.

Here is my current function

```
public CourseList(): Observable < ICourse[] > {
  return this.CourseworkServ.Read()
    .pipe(
      switchMap((CurrentCourses: IResponseObject < ICourseworkData > ) => {
        return this.CourseServ.Read(this.SelectedDepartment.Id)
          .pipe(
            map((CourseList: IResponseObject < ICourse > ) => CourseList.Array.filter((CheckCourse: ICourse) => CurrentCourses.Array.some(({
              Id,
              Edition,
              Institution,
              Department,
              Course
            }) => CheckCourse.Id === Id)))
          )
      })
    )
}
```

This function will show courses taken from the list of courses, what I need is a list of courses not taken.  But if I can't just use the `!==` in the Id compare because the result would never be true.  I need something like an inverse filter or something like that.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: This is nothing to do with observables, surely; you have two arrays and want to identify the items in one that do not have a match in the other.

Comment: What about `! CurrentCourses.Array.some(({Id, Edition, Institution, Department, Course}) => CheckCourse.Id === Id)`? [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns `true` if the passed predicate is true for at least one element (in your case if the course was taken). So, the inverse is exactly what you ask for.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, the problem isn't directly related to `observables` but the asynchronous state of the data does limit the solutions (at least the ones I came up with).  @FK82 that would be perfect, I didn't think that the result array would track the negative set.  I'll try it though, if it works that is exactly what I need so thank you.